# How do I turn off ABCpdf's paragraph indenting during a chain?

Tags: pdf, abcpdf

The project I'm working on uses a 3rd party component called ABCpdf to generate PDF documents.  It has this feature where you can "chain" text from one content area to the next, which we're using to flow text across columns.  You can also define an indent size to be used at the start of "paragraphs."

This is all great, except now I've just discovered that if I hand a paragraph of text to ABCpdf at the bottom of the column such that it needs to "chain" to the top of the next, ABCpdf thinks the top of the new column is the start of a new paragraph, and applies the indent there as well.  I can't seem to find a way to turn this off, either in the documentation or by experiment.

Has anyone else solved this problem?  (Or even run into it?)

Comment: blah, abcpdf is terrible. i'm soooo glad i don't have to deal with it anymore. http://syncfusion.com/products/pdf/backoffice/default.aspx

Comment: Man, TELL ME ABOUT IT.  Using ABCpdf is one of the few decisions on this project that got made before I came on board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And, in case this helps anyone else, I now have an answer.

It turns out that this is a bug with Version 6 - upgrading to the new Version 7 fixed the problem.  V7 only puts the indent where you'd expect.

Hope this helps someone else.